# Apply mask to a string (phone number)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want phone numbers saved to the db to be of the same format. Right now, it's done on the front-end with jquery.maskedinput plugin, and it looks something like this:

```
$('input').mask('+1 (111) 111-1111')
```

We're developing an API, so this functionality has to be moved to the back-end. Is there a way in ruby/rails to do the number formatting as simple as with jquery.maskedinput?I want phone numbers saved to the DB to be of the same format. Right now, it's done on the front-end with the "jquery.maskedinput" plugin, and it looks something like this:

```
$('input').mask('+1 (111) 111-1111')
```

We're developing an API, so this functionality has to be moved to the back-end. Is there a way in Ruby/Rails to do the number formatting as simple as with "jquery.maskedinput"?

Comment: A mask is a UI thing. When I type into a phone field, and the number updates before my eyes to match your lovely format... that's masking. You users will (probably) not be lurking at terminals `ssh`ed into your server, watching the logs... so masking on the server side is probably not going to be useful to you? I think what you want is validation. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you agree, I would check out the phone gem. https://github.com/carr/phone

Comment: What if the phone number is from a country that formats their numbers differently than you think they should be, or uses more digits? Don't format the number in the database, just store a string of digits, then format when you display the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take a look at the [phone](https://github.com/carr/phone) gem.

```
pn = Phoner::Phone.parse('+385915125486')
pn.format("+ %c (%a) %n") # => "+ 385 (91) 5125486"
```